# Power spectral density of a pulse

Tags: power-spectral-density, time-frequency, signal-power

A little background: I am simulating the response of an antenna to a pulse. The pulse has a wide frequency range, but the antenna only responds to a fairly narrow frequency. I can extract voltage and current from the antenna: they look like sinusoidal signals quickly decaying in time.

I now want to calculate the power spectral density (PSD) of that received signal. If I calculate the FFT of my voltage and current signals I see a nice isolated peak at the resonance frequency, so I would expect the power to also be concentrated around that frequency.

My first attempt was simply to multiply the voltage and current in time domain and then calculating the PSD of that. It did not work, the peak of the PSD happens at a frequency roughly double the expected one and at the desired frequency there is actually a "notch". I suspect that it is because by simply multiplying current and voltage I have effectively modulated one onto the other, therefore mixing their frequencies.

I can get a PSD that seem to make sense if instead I multiply the voltage and current in frequency domain and then calculate the PSD from the resulting spectrum.

So my questions are:

- Why can't I just calculate power as v*i in time domain?
- Does multiplying voltage and current spectra to then calculate the PSD make sense?

Comment: so let's answer your second question first: no. While the PSD is indeed a description of the power over frequency, it is not calculated from the power signal, but from the signal itself. No big deal, if you observe the current, the voltage contains zero additional info (and vice versa); your power is U·I consideration comes from a world where you'd tell apparent from real power, but that concept doesn't apply to RF.

Comment: Pulses don't have _power_, they have _energy_.  Power spectral densities exist for pulse _trains_ but not for individual pulses.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I understand that if I observe the current the voltage contains zero additional info. Yet, if I want to calculate how much power goes into my antenna, as if I were to measure it in reality, I would need to know the current and multiply the two, no?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: pulses have energy in the sense that, being contained in time, they allow me to calculate the total energy they contain. This is not possible for an infinitely long signal because that total would go to infinity. But they obviously still have power: my pulse will physically do work and the energy that the pulse have is the integration of that power over time. Or not?

Comment: @DrEarlGray as I said, no.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I'm sorry but that does not help me understand. If I know the current, the voltage will depend on the load my antenna is connected to. In the specifics of my example, the power transferred by my antenna to a load will be very different if I connect it to a matched load or to a short circuit. So either I know the load, or I know both current and voltage.

Comment: I'm having a hard time boiling the theory behind PSDs down to a comment, but let me try to give you an argument: A complex sinusoid has constant power; for every point in time, its envelope is constant. We know the shape of a sinusoid in the PSD: it's a dirac impulse with an area that is equal to its power. But: that complex sinusoid might be (half) a baseband representation of a real sine-shaped current that you measured,which definitely has periodic zeros in its current over time.But if you calculated power as current times voltage,you'd get periodic zeros–whereas in reality,it's constant!

Comment: I think you might be forgetting that your P = I·V formula only works if your I and V are considered complex currents or voltages, and you'll find that for radiating waves, they have the very peculiar property of having a relative phase that makes the power constant.

Comment: That was the "electrical engineer" argument for why the PSD must be calculated from either current or voltage, not from the product. As a stochastics guy, I'd simply argue that for a stationary process, it needs to be Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation function of that process for the desired properties (line spectra for periodic functions at – and only at – the inverse of every period duration) to hold true; you don't get that with the Fourier Transform of the Power, but with the Fourier Transform of the Amplitude Autocorrelation Function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks. I'll think about it some more